# Create an interactive Photomap with leaflet, JS. Trying to figure out how to size the photo to fit the state borders

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, size

Hello I am working on my first frontend JS leaflet project trying to make an interactive PhotoMap using pictures I personally took that I want to display on the map. I created clipped arts of all the states to the state size and wanted to fit those on the map in the borders of the specific state. I have been using the 'imageOverlay' feature with leaflet and using google maps I would get the corners of the state to use as my Lat/Lon for the 'imageOverlay'. Currently it shows up on the right state put no where near what the state size is or fitting exact to the borders. I will attach my main.js code and an image of the map currently

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOUuQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO2xA.png)